# Checar se android está em economia de energia

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu checar se o dispositivo android está em economia de energia. Já procurei em todo canto, inclusive na documentação oficial, e nada.

Answer (score 6):

A partir da versão 21(Lollipop) é possível verificar o *power save mode* através do método [isPowerSaveMode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isPowerSaveMode()) da classe **[PowerManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)** (que trata das questões de controle do  estado de energia do dispositivo), ele retornará `true` se o dispositivo estiver em "power save mode".

É também possível monitorizar mudanças no modo. Registe um *BroadcastReceiver* para responder ao *Intent* [ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#ACTION_POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED).
Ele será lançado sempre que houver um alteração no *power save mode*.

```
public class PowerSaveModeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        final PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (powerManager.isPowerSaveMode()) {
            // está em "power save mode"
        } else {
            // não está em "power save mode"
        }
    }
}
```

Faça o seu registo no AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerSaveModeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.os.action.POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED"/> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Me ajudou bastante, mas não o suficiente :/. Quero utilizar algum recurso que funcione pra todas as API's

Comment: Para enfatizar a resposta, adicione um link do PowerManager. +1